# Android Chat functionality, Choosing GCM implementation over HTTP or XMMP

Tags: android, http, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, chat

we have already implemented GCM over HTTP for our chat functionality, but after reading GCM XMPP [xmpp document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) and google states below benefits offered by xmpp

Benefits :-

> The asynchronous nature of XMPP allows you to send more messages with
>   fewer resources.
>
> Communication is bidirectional—not only can your server send messages
>   to the device, but the device can send messages back to your server.
>
> The device can send messages back using the same connection used for
>   receiving, thereby improving battery life.

we choose HTTP, since we are comfortable in developing using http rather than XMPP. but my concern is, will XMPP provides long term solution for our chat functionality?.

And i am not getting first two points, fewer resources (what exactly it is, when compared to HTTP), secondly, bi-directional messages, i see this can be achieved in HTTP either ,my flow diagram for http flow

[image]

i understand in http we need to create new connection when ever we need to invoke backend, so XMPP has advantage here. I would like to know is HTTP is right choice for chat functionality? for longer run..

Answer (score 1):

XMPP should be used over HTTP for continuous communication.

XMPP supports upstream messaging, with HTTP your client (phone) has to make an HTTP call to your app server, you cannot send an upstream message to GCM without XMPP.

XMPP makes fewer connections so overhead (battery, data etc) is much less than with HTTP.

Comment: can you please explain what is updstream message to GCM?, will this important aspect in chat functionality?

Comment: Upstream message to GCM is when the client (phone) sends message to GCM. Upstream requires XMPP, thus less connections which is more appropriate for chat applications. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream